# Failed to destroy the filter named [Engines Filter] of type [org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.filter.LazyProcessEnginesFilter]

Tags: spring-boot, camunda, camunda-modeler

I am running a springboot application and I am getting following error. It is not starting Camunda Engine. 
I have integrated camunda dependencies in this but still getting Lazy or null pointer exception. When i run the same application twice means 2 applications at the same time. One is running and another giving below error where configurations are same

PLease help. Thanks in Advance.

Exception:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableProcessApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableJms
public class CamundaApplication {

@Autowired
private RuntimeService runtimeService;
public static void main(String... args) {

SpringApplication.run(CamundaApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

Glimpse of dependency file:

```
dependencies {
    compile(group: 'org.camunda.bpm.springboot', name: 'camunda-bpm-spring- 
boot-starter', version: '3.0.0')
    {
    exclude module: 'spring-tx'
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
    exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }

compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-tx', version: 
'5.0.6.RELEASE'
compile(group: 'org.camunda.bpm.springboot', name: 'camunda-bpm-spring- 
boot-starter-webapp', version: '3.0.0')
{
exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
exclude module: "logback-classic"

}
compile(group: 'org.camunda.bpm.springboot', name: 'camunda-bpm-spring- 
 boot-starter-rest', version: '3.0.0')
{
exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
exclude module: "logback-classic"

}
compile group: 'org.camunda.bpm', name: 'camunda-engine-plugin-spin', version: '7.9.0'
compile group: 'org.camunda.spin', name: 'camunda-spin-dataformat-all', version: '1.6.0'
compile group: 'org.camunda.spin', name: 'camunda-spin-core', version: '1.6.0'
compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.196'
compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
```

Exception:

```
Failed to destroy the filter named [Engines Filter] of type [org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.filter.LazyProcessEnginesFilter]

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.filter.LazyDelegateFilter.destroy(LazyDelegateFilter.java:49) ~[camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:318) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:4670) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5470) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1437) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1426) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]

2019-02-19 17:20:27.241 ERROR 19396 --- [ost-startStop-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]                        : Failed to destroy the filter named [Security Filter] of type [org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.filter.LazySecurityFilter]

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.filter.LazyDelegateFilter.destroy(LazyDelegateFilter.java:49) ~[camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:318) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:4670) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5470) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1437) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1426) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]

2019-02-19 17:20:27.267  INFO 19396 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-02-19 17:20:27.271 ERROR 19396 --- [           main] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'nodeRPCConnection': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder '/canopy/dev/cleveland/quotes/config.rpc.port' in value "${/canopy/${env}/${member}/${app}/config.rpc.port}"
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:379) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:580) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at com.rba.camunda.quote.CamundaApplication.main(CamundaApplication.java:26) [classes/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder '/canopy/dev/cleveland/quotes/config.rpc.port' in value "${/canopy/${env}/${member}/${app}/config.rpc.port}"
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:88) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:62) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:531) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:137) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:133) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:85) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getPropertyAsRawString(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:74) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:145) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:839) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1086) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
... 17 more


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: This looks like some bug in your code: `Could not resolve placeholder '/canopy/dev/cleveland/quotes/config.rpc.port' in value "${/canopy/${env}/${member}/${app}/config.rpc.port}"`